# Shrinking the Select Element Handle

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there a way to narrow the select handles.

for instance

[image]

Narrowing down the actual handles on the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the width css property on the select tag, or left it as auto

Comment: I mean the handle, not the content area

Comment: Ohh, you can't do much about that. Unfortunately the stupid select tag inherits its style from the browser not the page. This why it looks different in every browser.

Comment: ty, but not even CSS3/HTML 5 is able to accomplish this?

Comment: as far know no, but I haven't looked too far into that because I usually have to cater to IE so it's kinda pointless. There are some jQuery plugins that can do it but all of them (that I have used) have cons out weighing the pros. Mostly either don;t open with the window, don't fire events properly or there too hard to get the value. Anyways that was my rant :)